# How can I add face recognition to WinForms using c++

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, winforms, face-recognition

Hello I am making a attendance system using WinForms Visual Studio now I want to add a face recongintion which will detect a students face. what can I use please give some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I hope OpenCV Can works for you .
[Example](https://github.com/MumbaiHackathon/FaceRecognito_Attendance_cpp)